# Keypress using mnemonics not initializing action

Tags: java, button, keypress, mnemonics

I have no idea why this isn't working. Netbeans does not allow me to edit this portion of the code.

```
        deletestudentButton.setText("Delete Student");
    deletestudentButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            deletestudentButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    deletestudentButton.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            deletestudentButtonKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });
```

However when go in to the Events in design mode and select keyPressed it gives me the following:

```
private void deletestudentButtonKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                               

     deletestudentButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
     deletestudentButton.setMnemonic(evt.VK_R);
      deletestudentButton.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {

    }
```

I figured thats where I should SetMnemonic. I tried two different statements, but when it compiles it does not initiate the keypress.

Comment: Do not use KeyListeners.  At all.  Right after you *create* the button, call its setMnemonic method.  Nothing else should be needed.  However, the mnemonic has to be a character that’s in the button’s text, so `KeyEvent.VK_R` won’t work.  Try `KeyEvent.VK_D` instead.

Comment: I got it to work! It was in the Properties of the Button itself in design mode.

Comment: Now to figure out how to get ctrl+d to work

Comment: Does your window have a menu bar?

Comment: a combobox? yes

Comment: *"Now to figure out how to get ctrl+d to work"* - Add a [key binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to the button

Comment: The mnemonic allows Alt-D to activate your button.  Why do you also need Ctrl-D to activate it?

Comment: It is part of an assignment I am doing for my Java class.